# What font does Xcode code use

Tags: xcode, fonts

When I type code in Xcode, I really like that font. I am interested in using it. Is it a classified font? Just would like to know...

Comment: Haha. Had the same question, however off topic.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The fonts name is `Menlo` and it comes with OS X.

Answer (score 5):

Preferences -> Fonts & Colors :))